# Count occurrences of values or unique values in a data range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

There's a formula that is so useful to me on http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/count-occurrences-of-values-or-unique-values-in-a-data-range-HP003056118.aspx

It's this:

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(MATCH(B2:B10,B2:B10,0),MATCH(B2:B10,B2:B10,0))>0,1))
```

Which is described on its site as: 
"Count the number of unique text and number values in cells B2:B10 (which must not contain blank cells)"

My problem is I need it to allow for blank cells interspersed in the range, but just not count those.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: In the link you provide, the last formula adds the condition *..but do not count blank cells or text values*. Does this one not work for you? (using `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` to enter it.)

Comment: It works on text for me. There is a misprint as if it was only designed for number values there would be `A2:A10` in place of `MATCH(A2:A10,A2:A10,0)` like the first formula.

Comment: I also have blanks.  The formula I supplied upstairs in the thread works on numbers and text, but not on blanks.

Comment: There appears to be some confusion. Please post some sample data and try the last formula (as posted by @Juliusz) and show why it does not work for you.

Comment: Lori, the formula that Julius references in the Microsoft site doesn't work anyway--even for things Microsoft says it works for.  Please try it to see for yourself.  Beyond that, even if that formula did work, the formula is defined to work only to "Count the number of unique text and number values in cells A2:A10 , but do not count blank cells or text values (6)."  I'll say again:  I have text values; I need text values counted.

Comment: Obviously the MS description is contradictory - it can't both "Count the number of unique `text` and number values......", but also "....not count blank cell or `text` values". That last part is wrong, it counts text and/or numbers, see my reply

Answer (score 2):

The formula posted by Juliusz works for me, it ignores blanks and counts the number of **different non-blank values** (I think the term "unique" is misused in the description), is that what you need?

The formula needs to be "array entered" with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER so that curly braces like { and } appear around the formula.

An alternative formula to give the same result (which doesn't need array entry) is

`=SUMPRODUCT((B2:B10<>"")/COUNTIF(B2:B10,B2:B10&""))`

Comment: This formula worked like a charm. But pls can anybody explain as how did the formula (division of SP arguments) actually work? And why the first argument of SumProduct and CountIf's 2nd arguments have been concocted with a 'blank'. In a bit details pls.

Answer (score 1):

But on the linked page there is the formula:

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(LEN(A2:A10)>0,MATCH(A2:A10,A2:A10,0),""), IF(LEN(A2:A10)>0,MATCH(A2:A10,A2:A10,0),""))>0,1))
```

which is described as:

> Count the number of unique text and number values in cells A2:A10 , but do not count blank cells or text values (6)

what is wrong with that one? It does allow to have blanks?

Comment: Despite repeated efforts to assist it seems we have not been understood perhaps because we were both insufficiently clear each time... but please don't assume it "doesn't work anyway" as it clearly does for others.

Comment: I think the formulas wasn't a chosen solution, because, in case of encountering any blank cells, the formula just returns blank result (just spares an 'error' msg). But the asker wanted that even in case of a blank cell in the range, the formula still should give some valid answer (which it doesn't).